# SSH prevent accidental lockout after configuration change

Tags: ssh

I have a server that I would like to change authentication methods for.

Is there a way to always ensure a valid, secure, login for SSH (or an alternative secure remote method to recover your ssh login), so you can fix things if they go horribly horribly wrong?

Comment: a possibly related workaround for iptable firewall changes to prevent lockout; essentially edit a file from a central point and check if it's not been touched for a while, if that's the case insert some iptables rules to recover access: http://pastebin.com/6h78MHrN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your out-of-band remote console (IPMI, iLO, DRAC, etc.).

If you can't use a remote console, start a temporary second copy of sshd on an alternate port with the original configuration, and connect with it to make your changes. If something goes wrong and the new sshd configuration breaks, you still have one running on an alternate port to connect with.

```
server # sshd -p 2222  # May also want to add -D, check the man page

client # ssh -p 2222 user@server
```

Comment: Can you update that to -f config_file.old, for clarity? (or is there something I'm missing)

Comment: You can do that if you want, yes.

Comment: So I'm guessing that the other instance will cache the config then. Just be sure to validate your changes before you kill or restart the second copy?

Comment: Precisely. Once you're sure the new config works, then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Like sitting in front of the Server while you're making changes? Or using IPMI.

Comment: Neither's an option on something like AWS.

Comment: Note that remote is a requirement.
Of course it's easy to login to the machine directly, if it's available locally.
As for IPMI, I like it, but as I'm running just some PC hardware on a low budget, I doubt it'll work for me.